# Is it possible to get redirect and 401 HTTP behavior in security filter chain?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Is it possible to redirect to "/login" when access to "/design", "/orders" without USER role and receive 401 HTTP error when access to "/api/**" unauthentificated? I use Spring Boot 2.7.10.

In code below it gives 401 for both cases. If I remove
`.exceptionHandling(configurer -> configurer.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)))` it redirects for both cases.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf()
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .mvcMatchers("/design", "/orders").hasRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling(configurer -> configurer
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            )
            .formLogin(
                    form -> form
                            .loginPage("/login")
                            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                            .defaultSuccessUrl("/design")
                            .permitAll()
            ).logout(
                    logout -> logout
                            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                            .permitAll()
            );
    return http.build();
}
```